# 2008 Ford Escape Hybrid - Ignition, electrical issue

Tags: electrical, ignition, starter, escape, hybrid

Sometimes when I try to start my 2008 ford escape hybrid rather than starting the electrical system freaks out.  Lights flicker, fans stop, doors lock, there is clicking from the steering column and other signs of poltergeist.  I tried locking a young priest and an old priest in the car for an evening, but after a few days of starting normally the seeming possession returned again only.  Sadly the local Catholic Church won't fall for the same trick which allowed me to trap the two priests last time.

Anyway...

Both times the electrical system freak out kind of went away after waiting for a few minutes and trying again.  The escape started perfectly after that.  So... It sounds like a short in the starter or ignition system to me, but I'm not a car person.

Any ideas about what might be the root cause of this out there?

Comment: The most common cause of this symptom is a poor connection at a battery terminal.